# Transmission line wave equation derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

[image]

Looking at the image, we write 
$$\Delta v=-(R\Delta x+j\omega L\Delta x)I$$

My question is, why is there no inclusion of the capacitor in this equation? I hope my wording makes sense. Is it because bothe the capacitor and the resistor are at the same potential?

Comment: because you already know the voltage drop through L and R and you measure the total relative to the common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your circuit model is wrong, you should use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations) model instead:

[image]

(Image by  By [Omegatron](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Omegatron))

Then the voltage drop across G and C will be the same.